# Moving from Shared Hosting to unmanaged VPS - Help setting up DNS / assigning domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, domain, name

I currently have an asp.net application on a new VPS.  My domain is registered with another register company.  From that company, I currently have the domain name server set up to point to a Custom Nameserver with my shared hosting account. Something like ns1.mysharedhosting.com and ns2.mysharedhosting.com.

My question is that with my VPS, I don't have these ns1 and ns2... So poking around my domain register I saw that I can use DNS Zone Editor to add an A record to point to my IP. instead of using the ns1.mysharedhosting.com.  Does this sound right?

Also, I have set up IIS, and have my website pulling up via it's IP already. Do I need to do anything else on my VPS for a DNS? or is that only if I want it to act as it's own seperate DNS? I get a little confused at that point.

One last side question, I have ready and still can't comprehend the difference between DNS and reverse DNS what they are used for, and if they normally reside on the same server as the webserver?  Any quick thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain registrar is also providing DNS services then just changing te A records to point to your VPS should work. There will be multiple A records required of you are looking to forward multiple URls (www.domain, mail,domain etc. ).

As far as setting up IIS goes, if you have one site listening for all traffic then you don't need to do anything further. Of you have multiple sites you will need to setup host headers.

Reverse DNS does, at the simplest level, the reverse of DNS, it maps up addresses to host names. It has many uses, one common one is for spam filtering, many large mail services check for a valid ptr record when delivering mail. Your reverse DNS information is usually setup on the same server as your forward DND zone.

Moving from shared hosting to a VPS is quite a big leap, if you are not sure what you are doing and your site is important then it may be worth considering getting some assistance with your setup.